# How to access html element by onclick value in C#?

Tags: c#, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to write a bot to read or database and fill an online HTML form.
during this process, there is a button on the form which needs to be clicked to edit the online form. I need to click that with C#.  The button looks like the following in DOM Explorer

[DOM Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAFZF.png)

As the code shows the element does not have ID.
I have tried the following codes none of them works

```
HtmlElementCollection buttons = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (HtmlElement btn in buttons)
        {
            if (btn.InnerText != null)
            {
                if (btn.InnerText.Equals("Edit"))
                {

                    btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                    btn.RaiseEvent("onclick");
                }
            }

        }
```

I also have tried the following;

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        HtmlElement wanted;

        foreach (HtmlElement item in elements)
        {
            if (item.GetAttribute("onclick") == "edit(this,'bss','fieldsurveyportal');")
            {
                wanted = item;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I am not sure even this possible or not! Az when I count the number of Button tags in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button") it is alot less than what it is in DOM Explorer